# Can Python run XSLT-2.0 transforms *and* call extension functions written in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xslt-2.0, saxon-c

I developed a set of XSLT-2.0 XML-to-XML transforms with Oxygen that include some simple `xsl:functions`. Now, I wish to run some functions on the nodes that are beyond what xsl:functions can reasonably do. To be more precise, I want to call an xsl:function extension in python that calls path-algorithms from the Python networkx library on node-sets.

Here's the problem:

- lxml lets me use [extension functions](https://lxml.de/extensions.html#xpath-extension-functions) but can't transform the XSLT-2.0 stylesheets
- saxon/c [interfaces with Python](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html) but doesn't *seem* to accept python extension libraries

How to get Python to run XSLT-2.0 transforms *and* call extension functions written in Python ?

Comment: If modules are not available, have Python call installed [external processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) with `subprocess` that can run XSLT 2.0.

Comment: In Saxon/C we support user defined functions written in C++ and PHP, but it is not yet available for the python extension.
I did look at this feature for Saxon/C 1.2 release, but it was not possible to include it at the time. We will look at implementing this feature request again for the next release.

Comment: @ond1 it was surprising to note support for C++ and PHP but not Python, given the growing importance of the latter. I'm looking forward to support for Python UDF's lest I can unleash the imperative and declarative powers of Python and XPath/XSLT respectively.   
Meanwhile, I'm considering calling UDFs from a java library using a saxon pe to do the heavy lifting as a workaround.

Comment: For many years Saxon/C supported only C++ and PHP languages. But in the last release we now provide a python extension.

Comment: @ond1 (Sep 27, 2020 at 5:23): Has the current SaxonC 12.4 version now enabled the use of custom Python functions in the XSLT template?
Something like the following example: 
#XSLT
<xsl:value-of select="my:python_Func('Hello')"/>

#python
def python_Func(dummy, value_1):
   return f'{value_1} World'

If it is possible, could you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry this is still not possible and apologies it would be nice to have this feature working again. I will see if we can push on with getting this feature to work.